# Prove Fubini theorem holds for following function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $v\in L^{p}(\Bbb{R})$ for some $1\le p\le \infty$.Let $\rho\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$,and $\varphi\in C_c(\Bbb{R}).$,assume that $\rho$ has compact support.

1. Prove that following function $$\rho(x-y)v(y)\varphi(x) \in L^1(\Bbb{R}_x\times \Bbb{R}_y)$$
2. Does this result holds if $\rho$ does not has compact support.

My attempt if we can prove that:

$$\int(\int |\rho(x-y)v(y)\varphi(x)|dx)dy<\infty$$ then we are done.

To prove this ,first since $\varphi$ has compact supp.we have integral domain for the inner integrand is $K$ for some compact set.

Since $\rho$ has compact support.$x-y \in C$ for some compact set.since $x$ range in $K$ we have $y\in K-C  = \tilde{K}$ is also compact so we have :

$$\int(\int |\rho(x-y)v(y)\varphi(x)|dx)dy \le \int_{\tilde{K}}(\int_K|\rho(x-y)v(y)\varphi(x)|dx)dy\le C \int_{\tilde{K}}|v(y)|(\int_K|\rho(x-y)|dx)dy$$

Since $\int_K|\rho(x-y)|dx = \int_{K-y}|\rho(x)|dx$ as $y$ range in some compact set we have $$\int_{K-y}|\rho(x)|dx \le \int_{K-\tilde{K}}|\rho(x)|dx \le C_1$$ such that $C_1$ does not depend on $y$. so we have $$\int_{\tilde{K}}|v(y)|(\int_K|\rho(x-y)|dx)dy \le C_1 \int_{\tilde{K}}|v(y)|dy < \infty$$ which is the desired result,is my proof correct ,is there some better proof.

Does this result holds if $\rho$ is not compactly supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\iint|\rho(x-y)||v(y)||\varphi(x)|dx\times dy\\
&=\int\left(\int|\rho(x-y)||v(y)|dy\right)|\varphi(x)|dx\\
&=\int\left(\int|\rho(z)||v(x-z)|dz\right)|\varphi(x)|dx\\
&=\int\left(\int|v(x-z)||\varphi(x)|dx\right)|\rho(z)|dz\\
&\leq\int\left(\int|v(x-z)|^{p}dx\right)^{1/p}\left(\int|\varphi(x)|^{p'}dx\right)^{1/p'}|\rho(z)|dz\\
&=\int\left(\int|v(x)|^{p}dx\right)^{1/p}\left(\int|\varphi(x)|^{p'}dx\right)^{1/p'}|\rho(z)|dz\\
&=\|v\|_{L^{p}}\|\varphi\|_{L^{p'}}\|\rho\|_{L^{1}}\\
&<\infty,
\end{align*}
where $1/p+1/p'=1$, here $p<\infty$.

For that $p=\infty$, one has
\begin{align*}
\int|v(x-z)||\varphi(x)|dx\leq\|\varphi\|_{L^{\infty}}\int|v(x-z)|dx,
\end{align*}
the rest are the same.