# Why compact support assumption is necessary for the following proof: that $Dv_\epsilon = (Dv)_\epsilon$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I was reading Brezis's functional analysis,Sobolev spaces,and partial differential equation book.

In page 211,there is a therem which roughly speaking says $Du_\epsilon = (Du)_\epsilon$ where $u_\epsilon = u\star \eta_\epsilon$.

Which is proved as follows:

> Lemma 8.4. Let $\rho \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $v \in W^{1,
>  p}(\mathbb{R})$ with $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. Then $\rho \star v \in$
> $W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$ and $(\rho \star v)^{\prime}=\rho \star
>  v^{\prime} .$

Proof. First, suppose that $\rho$ has compact support. We already know (Theorem 4.15) that $\rho \star v \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$. Let $\varphi \in C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R}) ;$ from Propositions $4.16$ and $4.20$ we have
$$
\int(\rho \star v) \varphi^{\prime}=\int v\left(\check{\rho} \star \varphi^{\prime}\right)=\int v(\check{\rho} \star \varphi)^{\prime}=-\int v^{\prime}(\check{\rho} \star \varphi)=-\int\left(\rho \star v^{\prime}\right) \varphi,
$$
from which it follows that
$$
\rho \star v \in W^{1, p} \quad \text { and } \quad(\rho \star v)^{\prime}=\rho \star v^{\prime} .
$$

This is the first part of the proof,which assume $\rho$ to be compacted supported.The question is where do we use the assumption that $\rho$ is compact support.One possible case may be the first equality which uses the Fubini theorem.But as the post shows [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4127630/360262) it seems not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\rho$ does not have compact support, then $\rho * \phi$ might not have compact support in general. Then it could not be used as test function in
$$
\int v(\rho * \phi)'= -\int v' (\rho*\phi),
$$
as the definition of weak derivative demands a test function with compact support.